# if condition and counter increment

Tags: if-statement, counter, conditional-statements, increment

What wrong with this if condition?

```
  if ((@rent_amt_h <> '0.000') or (@house_payment_amt_h <> '0.000') or (@insurance_amt_h <> '0.000')or (@property_taxes_amt_h <> '0.000') or  (@gas_amt_u <> '0.000') or (@elec_amt_u <> '0.000') or (@otherfuel_amt_u <> '0.000') or (@Trash_Collection_amt_u <> '0.000') or (@Sewerage_amt_u <> '0.000') or (@Telephone_amt_u <> '0.000') or (@water_amt_u <> '0.000') or (@other_house_amt_h <> '0.000') or (@other_amt_u <> '0.000') or (@total_u <> '0.000'))

                           begin
                 SET @APPSHELTER_COUNT  =  (select Count(APP_ID) FROM ext_app_group_other_expenses (nolock)  WHERE APP_ID = @App_Id )
               end
               else
               begin
                 SET @APPSHELTER_COUNT  =  0
               end
```

It increments the @APPSHELTER_COUNT value, even the values in if condition are zero!. It never sets the value to 0?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you have 14 clauses in your if statement - that's difficult to read and impossible to maintain

Answer (score 1):

What language is that? Anyway, it feels like you are comparing numbers with strings. Try removing quotes around your zeros. For example `@rent_amt_h <> 0` rather than `@rent_amt_h <> '0.000'`. Also, if that is some SQL, make sure you handle [`NULL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) correctly, because `NULL != 0`.

Comment: @userstackoverflow: anytime :)